# Python Spider: Extract certain word form results

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how I can extract only a part of text in a list.

Below is my script that I'm currently use:

```
import scrapy.selector 
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from MediaMarkt.items import MediamarktItem


def complete_url(string):
    return "http://www.mediamarkt.be" + string


def encode(str):
    return str.encode('utf8', 'ignore') 


class MshbeSpider(Spider):
    name = "mshbetv"
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_TV,98952,452540.html?langId=-17']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//*[@id="filters"]/form/fieldset[2]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a/@href')
        for item in items:
            link = item.extract()
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response): 
        items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="products-list"]/li/div')
        for item in items:
            mshtv = MediamarktItem()
            mshtv['item_3_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0]).replace("-","")
            mshtv['item_2_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_a_link'] = complete_url(item.select('.//div/h2/a/@href').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_4_avai'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/ul/span/text())').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_1_cat'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="category"]/hgroup/h1/text())').extract()[0])
            yield mshtv


        new_link = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
        yield Request(complete_url(new_link),callback=self.parse_category)
```

The field "mshtv['item_2_name'] " is where I want to extract only certain text.
If tried everything that I could find but without succes.

With my current script the results I'm getting for "mshtv['item_2_name']" are for example

- TV SAMSUNG UE55J6200AWXXN 55" LCD FULL LED Smart TV SONY
- KDL55W755CBAEP 55" LCD EDGE LED Smart
- TV SONY KD55-X9405CBAEP 55" 4K

I have a hole list of the correct manufactor model numbers. As in this example they are

- UE55J6200AWXXN
- KDL55W755CBAEP
- KD55X9405CBAEP

What I want to achieve is that while running my script I'm only getting the manufactor model numbers as return.

Is this uberhaupt possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the list of correct model numbers in a dict, then split the string containing a model number into words on space and lookup in the dict.

```
d = {}
for model in models:
    d[model] = True
for word in mshtv['item_2_name'].split(" "):
    if word in d:
        print word
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply emh. But where do I put this in my script?

Comment: @Wouter Put the dictionary initialization (3 first lines) somewhere it is only run once, such as top of script. The last 3 lines you can put in parse_category function. Probably you want to do mshtv['item_model'] = word or similar instead of print word as well.

Comment: I've tried it but I getting an error saying that "models" isn't defined

Comment: You said you had a list of valid models in your question: "I have a hole list of the correct manufactor model numbers." You should set models to that list. If they are in a file, one per line, you can do: models = []; for line in open("models.txt", "r"): models.push(line.strip("\n"))

Comment: Please see my question below. You're offered solution works but no I don't manage to scrape the whole site, while before this was working.

Comment: @Wouter The indentation of "yield mshtv" line is wrong. You should indent it one step.

Answer (score 0):

After I've tried the solution that "ehm" proposed I've tried it.
It works but something else is wrong now. I'm only getting 13 results while before I got over 200 results.

```
import scrapy.selector 
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from MediaMarkt.items import MediamarktItem

models = ["ue78js9500lxxn","UE60J6200AWXXN","kdl40w705cbaep","KDL55W755CBAEP","KDL40W705CBAEP"]
d = {}
for model in models:
    d[model] = True

def complete_url(string):
    return "http://www.mediamarkt.be" + string


def encode(str):
    return str.encode('utf8', 'ignore') 


class MshbeSpider(Spider):
    name = "mshbetv"
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_TV,98952,452540.html?langId=-17']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//*[@id="filters"]/form/fieldset[2]/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a/@href')
        for item in items:
            link = item.extract()
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response): 
        items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="products-list"]/li/div')
        for item in items:
            mshtv = MediamarktItem()
            mshtv['item_3_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0]).replace("-","")
            mshtv['item_2_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_a_link'] = complete_url(item.select('.//div/h2/a/@href').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_4_avai'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/ul/span/text())').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_1_cat'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="category"]/hgroup/h1/text())').extract()[0])
            for word in mshtv['item_2_name'].split(" "):
                if word in d:
                    mshtv['item_model'] = word
        yield mshtv


        new_link = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
        yield Request(complete_url(new_link),callback=self.parse_category)
```